# How to filter out HTML tags from within a div tag using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, domparser

I have this HTML code:

```
<div>
    756
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Using JavaScript I want to retrieve the number 756 from within the `div` tag and increment it by 1.  What is the best method of filtering out the `<span>` from within the div tags so I get only the number?

Comment: The simplest way to do it is to place the number in another span and access the new span instead of the div with javascript

Comment: use `.innerText` and then parseInt (don't forget the radix)

Comment: Is the structure shown always the same, and number always goes first in that div? Or you need more flexible solution?

Comment: Sorry a bit late but posted an alternative that avoid the browser incompatibility. var theNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML.match(/\d+/), 10);
alert(theNum+=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0],
    content = div.textContent || div.innerText;
```

`textContent` is supported by all browsers except IE8- and `innerText` is supported in all browsers except FF4-. So using both, you should get a stable result.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html

Both properties return the text content with stripped HTML tags.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HnWxk/ (tested in chrome/ff/ie7)

Now, if you want to increment it, just do:

```
content++;
```

It should cast a Number: http://jsfiddle.net/HnWxk/3/

Comment: Most elegant solution :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.innerText` to do so.

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];

var inner;
if(div.innerText) {
   inner = div.innerText;
} else {
   inner = div.textContent;
}

var number = parseInt(inner);
number++;
alert(number);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fzWXN/1/).

Comment: Just read here that indeed Firefox has problems with the ".innerText". Just updated the code to work with .textContent for Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="mydiv">
    756
    <span></span>
</div>

<script>
  var textNode = document.getElementById("mydiv").childNodes[0];
  var number = parseInt(textNode.nodeValue);
  textNode.nodeValue= number + 1;
</script>​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3jYKa/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just an other way to do it without the browser incompatibility of innerText and textContent. I use innerHTML after I use a regular expression to extract the number, Also it is recommended to always define the radix when you use parseInt (will simply avoid some weird surprise I let you discover) and finally incrementing the value.

```
var theNum = parseInt(document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML.match(/\d+/), 10);
alert(theNum+=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to wrap the number in its own `<span>`.
If that is not possible (you don't create the HTML code), you can iterate over all child nodes of the `<div>`. One of them will be the text node you want to target.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="number">
    756
    <span></span>
</div>​


d = document.getElementById("number")
n = parseInt(d.innerHTML)+1;
alert(n)​;​
```

Comment: retracting. Sorry. Number(...) returns NaN, but parseInt(...) does return 756

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this html code:

```
<div id="someDiv">
  756
  <span></span>
</div>
```

You can use this (with jquery):

```
var div = $("#someDiv");
div.text(parseInt(div.text()) + 1);
```

Comment: Or just `div.text()+1`. Also, jQuery was not tagged and your code will remove any HTML inside the container.

Comment: The title simply says with "javascript" and the answer will be relevant if the title said with "jQuery" Sorry this is the reason why I voted the answer as not being useful

Answer (score 0):

I used split on the text to get the number.
Also used jQuery to get the text, you can use the other methods people used here.

```
var divText = $('div').text();
var contentArray = divText.split('\n');       
var yay = parseInt(contentArray[1].trim(), 10);
alert(yay);
alert(yay++);
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bldoron/HGtnJ/2/).

Comment: Assumes a newline in the sourcecode. Splitting by `/\s?</` would be better.

Comment: @JanDvorak You have to work with some kind of agreed format, I assumed his example represented that format. The regexp you offered is indeed better. 10x.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be wrap the number in an element, but  you can workaround with [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qFagm):

```
var div = document.getElementById('div')
var num = parseInt((div.innerText) ? div.innerText : div.textContent);
div.childNodes[0].nodeValue = num + 1;
```